# Under what conditions are National Guard units subject to general orders/regulations in effect for the U.S. Military?

Tags: united-states, military

Related to and inspired by [my prior question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/74561/does-the-secretary-of-defenses-vaccine-mandate-constitute-a-legal-general-order).

The Secretary of Defense has issued a vaccine mandate for the Department of Defense, which includes all subordinate commands.  Assuming that this constitutes a general order which members of the military are obliged to respect and obey, the fact that the Governor of Oklahoma recently issued a countermanding order suggests that National Guard units are not subject to the totality of the rules and regs that government the Department of Defense.

I know that UCMJ doesn't apply to a National Guard unit until/unless it's activated under POTUS' Title X powers, but it seems odd to me that a unit readiness issue like this would also not apply.  Assuming there was an emergency that warranted the activation of the OK Nat'l Guard, they'd need time to procure and administer vaccines, plus possibly six more weeks for the 2nd dose + 2 week potency period (unless they got J&J).

So now I'm curious: What DoD rules/regs apply to National Guard units that aren't yet activated? Is there any pathway for culpability to land on the service members themselves? (Presumably onto the general staff, it'd be particularly unfortunate for it to reach all the way to the enlisted.)